# Remove milliseconds in SQL commands

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Having this kind of SQL Statement, how can I remove milliseconds from the 'date_created' column?

```
SELECT sales.id,
       sales.filename,
       account.description customer,
       sales.uploaded,
       sales.date_created
  FROM account
       JOIN salesStore sales
            ON sales.customer_id = account.id
 WHERE sales.date_created::date BETWEEN '2014-02-27' 
                                    AND '2014-03-01'
ORDER BY 
       sales.date_created DESC
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove milliseconds or time component altogether? Your where clause seems to indicate you're only interested in the date.

Comment: @sam yi - only the milliseconds I want to remove from my date_created column.

Comment: The original data type of the column `sales.date_created` should be in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
 DATE_TRUNC('second', sales.date_created);
```

See the docs for [DATE_TRUNC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

[postgresql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Answer (score 4):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> `time`, `timestamp`, and `interval` accept an optional precision value *`p`*
>   which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the
>   seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision.
>   The allowed range of *`p`* is from 0 to 6 for the `timestamp` and `interval`
>   types.

You can cast to `timestamp(0)` (or `timestamptz(0)`) to remove fractional seconds:

```
date_created::timestamp(0)
```

This ***rounds*** to full seconds - as opposed to [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) which ***truncates***.

Answer (score 2):

`DATE_FORMAT(sales.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')` for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

For other sql engines it might be different and you will have to precise which you are using.

Edit: add `%H:%i:%s` to keep the date component as well.

**Update**

For PostgreSQL, see [PostgreSQL's Documentation for Data Type Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html), or [[SO] How to compare dates in datetime fields in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469154/how-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-fields-in-postgresql) which gives several options for date comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will remove millisecond part from date.

```
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date), date)
```