# ERROR: function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, datetime-format

I am doing a website that having a booking function. And I would like to have a list of booking(s) that on my current date in view.

I have following code on my controller:

```
def today
@vlts = Vlt.where("strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date_time) = ?", Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
end
```

And I have following code in my view:

```
<% @vlts.each do |vlt| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= vlt.date_time %></td>
    <td><%= vlt.name %></td>
    <td><%= vlt.phone_no %></td>
    <td><%= vlt.no_ppl %></td>
    <td><%= vlt.message %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_vlt_path(vlt) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', vlt, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

But when I run my page on http://localhost:3000/today, I received following error that made me scratch my head.

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "vlts".* FROM "vlts" WHERE (strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date...
>                                              ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   : SELECT "vlts".* FROM "vlts" WHERE (strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date_time) = '18/01/2018')

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` is a Ruby function. You can't invoke it inside a database query. If you want to compare two timestamps as dates in a query, you need to use SQL's functions, not Ruby's.

See [How to compare dates in datetime fields in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469154/how-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-fields-in-postgresql)