# Add variable to count consecutive months

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a query in a Postgres DB that combines clients subscriptions.

I want to add a variable that's called "consecutive months" but I'm not sure how to do it in Postgres.

My raw table is something like this:

| client | product | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sub | 2020-10-01 |
| 1 | Sub | 2020-11-01 |
| 2 | Sub | 2020-11-01 |
| 2 | Sub | 2020-12-01 |
| 1 | Sub | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | Sub | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | Sub | 2021-02-01 |

and I inteed to have something that counts the consecutive months originating something like this:

| client | product | Date | Consecutive_months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sub | 2020-10-01 | 1 |
| 1 | Sub | 2020-11-01 | 2 |
| 2 | Sub | 2020-11-01 | 1 |
| 2 | Sub | 2020-12-01 | 2 |
| 1 | Sub | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | Sub | 2021-02-01 | 2 |
| 2 | Sub | 2021-02-01 | 1 |

Thank you for the help in advanced!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469154/how-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-fields-in-postgresql

Comment: that question doesn't seem similar at all ?

Comment: That question is about time intervals, I'm trying to do something similar but adding a variable that it's continuously increasing. I can't figure how to store the variable or even when to start it .. How can you refere to prod(previous report) when looking on february 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got yourself a Gaps-And-Islands type of problem.

The trick is to calculate some ranking based on connected dates per client.

Then a sequencial number can be calculated based on client and the rank.

> ```
> select client, product, "Date"
> , row_number() over (partition by client, daterank order by "Date") as Consecutive_months
> from
> (
>   select "Date", client, product
>   , dense_rank() over (partition by client order by "Date") 
>     + (DATE_PART('year', AGE(current_date, "Date"))*12 + 
>        DATE_PART('month', AGE(current_date, "Date"))) daterank
> from raw t
> ) q
> order by "Date", client
> ```
>
> ```
> client | product | Date       | consecutive_months
> -----: | :------ | :--------- | -----------------:
>      1 | Sub     | 2020-10-01 |                  1
>      1 | Sub     | 2020-11-01 |                  2
>      2 | Sub     | 2020-11-01 |                  1
>      2 | Sub     | 2020-12-01 |                  2
>      1 | Sub     | 2021-01-01 |                  1
>      1 | Sub     | 2021-02-01 |                  2
>      2 | Sub     | 2021-02-01 |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1a0705150cc5fb72b091f8a3484f5e85)*

Comment: Thank you guys! I manage to do it and now I'm familiarized with those funtions (my DW is in BQ, had to do some modifications).

Two questions: Why do we multiply by 12? Is it possible to make it count throughout the years? When going from 2020 to 2021 the count goes back to 0

Comment: A year has 12 months,  so a range of '3 year 6 months' give `3*12+6=42` months total. Not sure about the years thing. Probably not? But I suggest adding more test data to the test code to verify.

Comment: I found it! To "forget" the change of the year and keep countig it's just a 
```
DATE_DIFF(current_date, "Date", Month)
```
At least on BQ. Thank you @LukStorms

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tag OP apparently realizes this is a gaps and island problem. This query extracts month and year information to generate a sequence that increments on a monthly basis. After that it's only necessary to use the standard difference logic to find the rows that move out of step and create mark off the islands.

```
with A as (
    select *,
        date_part('year', dt) * 12 + date_part('month', dt)
          - row_number() over (partition by client, product order by dt) as grp
    from T
)
select *,
    row_number()
        over (partition by client, product, grp order by dt) as consecutive_months
from A;
```

If it's acceptable to have multiple rows falling in the same month for a given client-product then switch `row_number()` to `dense_rank()` in both places.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=397a2f3282cab3b70bd7a47d1dc5ea0a